# How do I get rid of automatic ordering of numeric properties?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have an object `newData` where I assign properties to it like so:

```
newData['5'] = 'test 1';
newData['3'] = 'test 2';
newData['8'] = 'test 3';
```

I get:

```
{
    '3': 'test 2',
    '5': 'test 1',
    '8': 'test 3'
}
```

But I want to maintain insertion order of properties, such that this is what I get:

```
{
    '5': 'test 1',
    '3': 'test 2',
    '8': 'test 3'
}
```

Where 5, 3, and 8 stay in the order of insertion. JavaScript objects should not have an order, but it obviously does... and this is severely messing up the loop.

I have to have keys and since JavaScript arrays don't support custom keys, this needs to be an object. How do I add to an object and keep it unordered as it is supposed to be?

Comment: Why do you need it to be ordered? can you show how you are consuming the object?

Comment: Objects aren't ordered by design but it doesn't mean that it can't be stored that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object properties **do** have a certain order, differing from insertion order. It's described in the [ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-ownpropertykeys):

> **9.1.12 [[OwnPropertyKeys]] ( )**
>
> When the [[OwnPropertyKeys]] internal method of *O* is called the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let *keys* be a new empty [List](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-list-and-record-specification-type).
> 2. For each own [property key](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-type) *P* of *O* that is an integer index, in **ascending numeric index order**
>
>    a. Add *P* as the last element of *keys*.
> 3. For each own [property key](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-type) *P* of *O* that is a String but is not an integer index, in property creation order
>
>    a. Add *P* as the last element of *keys*.
> 4. For each own [property key](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-type) *P* of *O* that is a Symbol, in property creation order
>
>    a. Add *P* as the last element of *keys*.
> 5. Return *keys*.

In the above, the properties are defined as the List *keys*. Then, when a property that is an integer is encountered, it is added to List *keys* in *ascending numeric order*, thus leading to 3, 5, 8 you observe.

If you want ordered keys and value pairs that respects order based on insertion, you must use something that respects order, such as an ES6 [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Per the documentation:

> **A Map object iterates its elements in insertion order** — a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop returns an array of `[key, value]` for each iteration.

Here's an example:

```js
const obj = new Map([
  [5, "test 1"],
  [3, "test 2"],
  [8, "test 3"]
]);

for(let [key, value] of obj) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

First, you pass an array of arrays to the constructor. The `Map` constructor takes in an iterable, and uses the subarrays as key and value pairs. The `Map` essentially looks like this:

```
+-----+----------+
| Key | Value    |
+-----+----------+
|  5  | "test 1" |
|  3  | "test 2" |
|  8  | "test 3" |
+-----+----------+
```

Next you use a `for...of` loop to iterate over the `Map`. As noted in the documentation, an array of `[key, value]` is returned by the iterator so you can use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Thus, `key` and `value` hold the values of the keys and values of the `Map` respectively, and logging them provides the desired, ordered result.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). It respects traversal based on insertion order.